# ¿Cómo actualizar mi tabla Inmuebles cuando haga una venta?

Tags: mysql

Quiero hacer un Disparador en MySQL dónde me borre un inmueble que ya está vendido en mi tabla de operaciones cuando se hace una venta:

```
Create Table inmueble
(
ID Char(5) primary key,
Precio float,
Tipo_inmueble varchar (30),
Ubicación varchar(30),
Superficie varchar(30)
)

Create Table venta
(
ID Char(5),
Fecha date,
Datos_Contrato varchar (30),
Monto Float,
ID_inmueble
Constraint Foreign Key (ID_inmueble) References inmueble (ID)
)
```

Realice un método `insert`, `update` y `delete` a los dos por separado.

**Nota**:
Estoy usando XAMPP con el servicio y módulo de MySQL con Apache

Answer (score 0):

Quiza esto te ayude:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `borrar_inmueble_por_venta` AFTER INSERT ON `venta`
 FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.ID_inmueble IS NOT NULL THEN
        delete from inmueble where ID = NEW.ID_inmueble;
    END IF
```

Te adjunto un resultado de ejecución:

[image: Imagen Trigger]

Saludos!

Comment: Al tratar de hacer eso, el disparador si me aparece pero al añadirlo a ventas me aparece una ventana llamada : error #1452 No se puede añadir o actualizar la llave hija.

Comment: Se me olvidó eso , lo que sucede es que cómo estás enlazando con un foreign key, no te deja eliminar por que queda huérfano el registro de ventas. Lo que puedes hacer para no eliminar la llave, es no eliminar con el trigger sino más bien añadir una columna de estado o algo y que cambie a no disponible o similar.